# Asking question read permissions in compose - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, android-external-storage

I have read and write permissions in `Compose`, the permissions are correctly added in my manifest. This's the button that I use to ask for permission:

```
@Composable
fun PermissionButton(
    toast: () -> Unit
) {
    val readWriteFilePermissionResultLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(),
        onResult = {isGranted ->
            if (
                isGranted.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == true
                && isGranted.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == true
            )  {
                toast()
            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "ERROR PERMISSION NOT GRANTED")
                Log.e("MainActivity", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = ${isGranted.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)}")
                Log.e("MainActivity", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = ${isGranted.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)}")
            }
        }
    )
    Button(onClick = {
        val permissions = arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        )
        readWriteFilePermissionResultLauncher.launch(
            permissions
        )
    }) {
        Text("Permission asking button")
    }
}
```

Those are the versions:

```
   compileSdk 33
   minSdk 30
   targetSdk 33
```

I tried out this button and the permissions are not asked to the user and the `onResult` is called with both permissions not granted.

I want to be able to read a file from the external storage.

Comment: You are on an Android sdk 33 device it seems.

Comment: Yes, the phone I'm using is on 33, but still encounter the problem on sdk 30. How did you know it was 33 ?

Comment: On a 33 device you should not ask for those permissions. Its in the docs.